# Wordpress Different Title Image in Category/Archive page

Tags: wordpress

I would to ask how can I have a different background image for each post category in my category template. My category template is custom.

Ex.

My post category is Living Room and I want an image of living room and another post category is Bedroom and I want a bedroom image and so on for all my categories.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ACF Plugin create a or more field  and put code to Archive or Category file in your Template

[Read Document Tip ACF Category here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-taxonomy-term/)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @dinhcode you can use advanced custom fields to add custom fields to your category taxonomy and use this field to setup images for the taxonomy term and then get the image object/url (whatever you have set as output while creating the field in acf).

Below is a small sample code:

```
get_header(); 


// get the current taxonomy term
$term = get_queried_object();


// assuming you have used image as field name and the output is set to url
$image = get_field('image', $term);
```

Comment: Hello again 

I have installed ACF, I created a field group and field, (field name image), upoaded the image from the input field in categories and used the above code

<?php
/**
* A Simple Category Template
*/
 
get_header(); ?> 


<?php $term = get_queried_object();?>
<?php $image = get_field('image', $term); ?>

<div class="fluid-container">
    <header class="archive-header">
        <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>"/>

and I got a broken image. I tried various options in ACF and in my code and still nothing.

Comment: Did you tried printing the image variable as `print_r($image);`